# JProfiler Installation could not create unpack process

Tags: java, jvm, jprofiler

I am trying to install jprofiler_windows_8_1_1.exe . I get this error in logs during installation. I am using windows7, I tried the 64 bit version also same error,

```
Trying c:\temp\e4j6494.tmp_dir1419369369\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll (exists 0)
Trying c:\temp\e4j6494.tmp_dir1419369369\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll (exists 1)
Loading of JVM-DLL successful
unpacking i4jruntime.jar.pack
c:\temp\e4j6494.tmp_dir1419369369\jre\bin\..\bin\unpack200.exe
-r "C:\Temp\e4j6494.tmp_dir1419369369\i4jruntime.jar.pack" "C:\Temp\e4j6494.tmp_dir1419369369\i4jruntime.jar"
could not create unpack process
emptying C:\Temp\e4j6494.tmp_dir1419369369
```

Comment: You might consider asking this question on SuperUser instead.

Comment: Any anti-virus software enabled? Try disabling it.